# How to write streaming Dataset to Cassandra?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

So I have a Python Stream-sourced DataFrame `df` that has all the data I want to place into a Cassandra table with the [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/15_python.md). I've tried doing this in two ways:

```py
df.write \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .mode('append') \
    .options(table="myTable",keyspace="myKeySpace") \
    .save() 

query = df.writeStream \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .outputMode('append') \
    .options(table="myTable",keyspace="myKeySpace") \
    .start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

However I keep on getting this errors, respectively:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "'write' can not be called on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;
```

and

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra does not support streamed writing.
```

Is there anyway I can send my Streamed DataFrame into a my Cassandra Table?

Answer (score 6):

There is currently no streaming `Sink` for Cassandra in the Spark Cassandra Connector. You will need to implement your own `Sink` or wait for it to become available.

If you were using Scala or Java you could use `foreach` operator and use a `ForeachWriter` as described in [Using Foreach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach).

Comment: Is there any way I can convert my Streaming DataFrame into a non-Streaming data frame?

Comment: No, there is no conversion (at least none that I know of)

Comment: Do you have a working example in Java? Looks all solutions come to `CassandraConnector.withSessionDo` which needs Scala implemented trait; so no luck with Kotlin or Java..

Comment: is this still true today (I mean 2018)?

Comment: In Spark 2.3 and beyond, when creating a custom sink, it looks like Spark does not allow you to call `.write()` on your dataframe in `addbatch` method. It throws the error that OP shared. Does anybody know what the alternative here is?

Comment: I haven't been working with Spark for a while now. Although I did manage to complete my small project, I'm not sure if this will help but you can see how I got past this. https://github.com/dretta/StockStats/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dretta/StockStats.scala https://github.com/dretta/StockStats/blob/master/Prototype/streaming-stocks.py The code doesn't actually work since the api I was using was modified and the call I'm making to it is deprecated.

Comment: Is this true as of Oct 2018?

Comment: It is only supported in DSE 6.0 which uses an enhanced version of the OSS code

Answer (score 5):

I know its an old post, updating it for future references.

You can process it as a batch from streaming data. like below

```py
def writeToCassandra(writeDF, epochId):
 writeDF.write \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .options(table="table_name", keyspace="keyspacename")\
    .mode("append") \
    .save()

query = sdf3.writeStream \
.trigger(processingTime="10 seconds") \
.outputMode("update") \
.foreachBatch(writeToCassandra) \
.start()
```

Comment: It's giving me error i.e. Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra.
I'm passing the package using --packages option.