# Writing Spark streaming PySpark dataframe to Cassandra overwrites table instead of appending

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm running a 1-node cluster of Kafka, Spark and Cassandra. All locally on the same machine.

From a simple Python script I'm streaming some dummy data every 5 seconds into a Kafka topic. Then using Spark structured streaming, I'm reading this data stream (one row at a time) into a PySpark DataFrame with `startingOffset` = `latest`. Finally, I'm trying to append this row to an already existing Cassandra table.

I've been following ([How to write streaming Dataset to Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113538/how-to-write-streaming-dataset-to-cassandra)) and ([Cassandra Sink for PySpark Structured Streaming from Kafka topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661075/cassandra-sink-for-pyspark-structured-streaming-from-kafka-topic)).

One row of data is being successfully written into the Cassandra table but my problem is it's being **overwritten** every time **rather than appended** to the end of the table. What might I be doing wrong?

Here's my code:

CQL DDL for creating `kafkaspark` keyspace followed by `randintstream` table in Cassandra:

```
DESCRIBE keyspaces;

CREATE KEYSPACE kafkaspark
  WITH REPLICATION = { 
   'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 
   'replication_factor' : 1 
  };
  
USE kafkaspark; 

CREATE TABLE randIntStream (
    key int,
    value int,
    topic text,
    partition int,
    offset bigint,
    timestamp timestamp,
    timestampType int,
    PRIMARY KEY (partition, topic)
);
```

Launch PySpark shell

```
./bin/pyspark --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1,spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions
```

Read latest message from Kafka topic into streaming DataFrame:

```
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("startingOffsets","latest").option("subscribe","topic1").load()
```

Some transformations and checking schema:

```
df2 = df.withColumn("key", df["key"].cast("string")).withColumn("value", df["value"].cast("string"))
df3 = df2.withColumn("key", df2["key"].cast("integer")).withColumn("value", df2["value"].cast("integer"))
df4 = df3.withColumnRenamed("timestampType","timestamptype")
df4.printSchema()
```

Function for writing to Cassandra:

```
def writeToCassandra(writeDF, epochId):
    writeDF.write \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .options(table="randintstream", keyspace="kafkaspark") \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

Finally, query to write to Cassandra from Spark:

```
query = df4.writeStream \
.trigger(processingTime="5 seconds") \
.outputMode("update") \
.foreachBatch(writeToCassandra) \
.start()
```

`SELECT *` on table in Cassandra:
[image]

Comment: please add the schema for your table and example of several rows of your data.

Comment: @Alex Ott Thanks for your response. I have edited my question above adding CQL DDL for creating keyspace & table along with screenshot from table showing one row being overwritten again and again from Spark.

Comment: It's giving me error i.e. Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. I'm passing the package using --packages option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the row is always rewritten in Cassandra, then you may have incorrect primary key in the table - you need to make sure that every row will have an unique primary key. If you're creating Cassandra table from Spark, then by default it just takes first column as partition key, and it alone may not be unique.

Update after schema was provided:

Yes, that's the case that I was referring - you have a primary key of `(partition, topic)`, but every row from specific partition that you read from that topic will have the same value for primary key, so it will overwrite previous versions. You need to make your primary key unique - for example, add the `offset` or `timestamp` columns to the primary key (although `timestamp` may not be unique if you have data produced inside the same millisecond).

P.S. Also, in connector 3.0.0 you don't need `foreachBatch`:

```
df4.writeStream \
  .trigger(processingTime="5 seconds") \
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
  .options(table="randintstream", keyspace="kafkaspark") \
  .mode("update") \
  .start()
```

P.P.S if you just want to move data from Kafka into Cassandra, you may consider the use of the [DataStax's Kafka Connector](https://docs.datastax.com/en/kafka/doc/index.html) that could be much lightweight compared to the Spark.

Comment: Thank you @Alex Ott. I think that may help explain the behaviour I was seeing. In my CQL DDL, I've set the PRIMARY KEY in Cassandara as composite of partition (PARTITION KEY) and topic (CLUSTERING KEY). Should I change my table schema in Cassandra to make the first column ("key") the PRIMARY KEY? Or is there any way to make Spark aware of Cassandra table PRIMARY KEY when writing to Cassandara?

Comment: I've updated the answer - Cassandra connector is automatically aware about primary key defined in the database

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott, will try using a unique PRIMARY KEY. Shall keep posted.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott, your suggestion was perfect. Adding offset to the PRIMARY KEY works. Now each row is appended to the table rather than overwritten. I've accepted and upvoted your answer. Thanks for your suggestion of using Kafka connector for writing to Cassandra; I think in my case Spark offers more flexibility for potentially adding more sophisticated processing in the future before writing to Cassandra.

Comment: Yes, if you need data processing, especially joins and aggregations, then you need Spark

Comment: Thanks. In Cassandra, is there any way to use the same column ("offset") as part of the PRIMARY KEY as well as CLUSTERING KEY? Basically, I want to order by offset ASC as well as add it to the PRIMARY KEY. Not sure if there's a workaround

Comment: Primary key consists of partition key, and clustering column(s)....

Comment: Right, sorry. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to change your partition key (first column in primary key) to topic or (topic, partition) - but it depends on your queries

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott. I've run into a related but different issue where no data gets written into Cassandra for a different streaming query. I'm now using a PySpark script executed via "spark-submit". I've posted as a new question. Would appreciate any ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539652/appending-streaming-pyspark-dataframe-to-cassandra-doesnt-write-anything