# Spark + Kafka app, getting "ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra"

Tags: python, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

Solved Link(but have the other bug haha... ) 
[spark stream cassandra, pyspark JNR is excluded from the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635850/spark-stream-cassandra-pyspark-jnr-is-excluded-from-the-classpath)

Python | spark  |  kafka  | Cassandra 
3.6.8  | 3.1.2  |  2.8.1  | [cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.8 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]

run code

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2 test.py
```

I succeeded in reading kafka topic with spark stream. So I tried to write the read topic to cassandra with writeStream, but it didn't work.

my code is on a different IP than the spark master IP.

this image is my Stream structor
ps. cassandra place masterIp
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ax3F.png)

my code

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

while True:
    # Spark Bridge local to master == Connect master
    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .master("spark://masterIp:7077") \
        .appName("Spark_Streaming+kafka+cassandra") \
        .getOrCreate()

    # Read Stream From test0003 at BootStrap
    df = spark.readStream \
      .format("kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "DBip:9092") \
      .option('startingOffsets','earliest') \
      .option('failOnDataLoss','False') \
      .option("subscribe", "test0003") \
      .load()

    df.printSchema()

    # write Stream at cassandra
    ds = df \
      .writeStream \
      .trigger(processingTime='15 seconds') \
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
      .outputMode('append') \
      .option("checkpointLocation","./kafka") \
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "master_Ip:9092") \
      .option("keyspace","testkey") \
      .option("table","testtable") \
      .start()



    break
```

error
I saw Traceback so checked my table, but i have testtable.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 30, in <module>
    .option("table","testtable") \
  File "./venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 1202, in start
  File "./venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "./venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 111, in deco
  File "./venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o47.start.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at
```

i reference this code
[Writing Spark streaming PySpark dataframe to Cassandra overwrites table instead of appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463238/writing-spark-streaming-pyspark-dataframe-to-cassandra-overwrites-table-instead)

if you feel this post unkind and foolish, sorry. i am 1month junior developer and this post my first post on stackoverflow

Comment: The exception is a `ClassNotFoundException`. This can point to the cassandra connector not being available on the worker. Try included the Maven coordinates to it in the submit command.  `spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0 test.py`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule thank you, too many traceback but i think it`s taken to the next step