# Appending streaming PySpark dataframe to Cassandra doesn't write anything

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm running Kafka, Spark and Cassandra locally on the same machine.

At 1-minute intervals I'm streaming some data into a Kafka topic (key is unix epoch in seconds and value is CPU temperature) and reading the latest offset into a PySpark streaming DataFrame. After a few basic column transforms, I'm trying to append this data to the end of a Cassandra table. The PySpark script seems to execute without error but no data is being written into Cassandra. What might I be doing wrong?

I've been following: (i) ([How to write streaming Dataset to Cassandra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113538/how-to-write-streaming-dataset-to-cassandra)), (ii) ([Cassandra Sink for PySpark Structured Streaming from Kafka topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58661075/cassandra-sink-for-pyspark-structured-streaming-from-kafka-topic)) and (iii) [Writing Spark streaming PySpark dataframe to Cassandra overwrites table instead of appending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64463238/writing-spark-streaming-pyspark-dataframe-to-cassandra-overwrites-table-instead/64464802?noredirect=1#comment113999819_64464802)

**CQL DDL to create table**

```
CREATE TABLE cputemperature (
    key bigint,
    value double,
    topic text,
    partition int,
    offset bigint,
    timestamp timestamp,
    timestampType int,
    PRIMARY KEY (value, offset)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (offset ASC);
```

**PySpark script**

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
import sys

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('OFF')

def helper_spark_source_kafka():
    '''
    This function reads latest offset of Kafka stream into a PySpark streaming dataframe, performs
    column data type conversions and returns streaming dataframe.
    '''
    try:
        df1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("startingOffsets","latest").option("subscribe","topic1").load()
        df2 = df1.withColumn("key", df1["key"].cast("string")).withColumn("value", df1["value"].cast("string"))
        df3 = df2.withColumn("key", df2["key"].cast("long")).withColumn("value", df2["value"].cast("double"))
        df4 = df3.withColumnRenamed("timestampType","timestamptype")
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[1])
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[2])
        sys.exit(1)
    return df4

def helper_spark_sink_cassandra(write_df, epoch_id):
    '''
    This function defines the Cassandra sink for PySpark streaming dataframe.
    '''
    write_df.write \
    .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
    .options(table="cputemperature", keyspace="kafkaspark")\
    .mode("append")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    streaming_df = helper_spark_source_kafka()

#    query_console = streaming_df.writeStream.format("console")
#    query_console.start().awaitTermination()

    query_cassandra = streaming_df.writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime="60 seconds") \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .foreachBatch(helper_spark_sink_cassandra)
    query_cassandra.start().awaitTermination()
```

**spark-submit command**

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1,com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.0.0 --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=127.0.0.1,spark.sql.extensions=com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraSparkExtensions $HOME/cputemplogs/pysparkscript.py
```

**Screenshot of `SELECT *` on Cassandra table**

[image]

Comment: are you sure that you have data processed correctly? Do you see data when output to console? You also don't need to use `foreachBatch` in the SCC 3.0.0 - just use .format("..cassandra"), etc.

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott. yes I think it's being processed correctly. I had it outputting to console first which was later commented out after adding in Cassandra sink (because apparently concurrent queries aren't supported at the moment). Also, I tried your suggestion of writing to Cassandra without `foreachBatch`. For this I first got an error about missing checkpointLocation option. Then when I added that in, it was complaining about receiving two arguments instead of one (table & keyspace) for the .options(...) accessor. So I reverted back to my old way which was working before in PySpark shell

Comment: Only thing I can think of is incompatible data type definitions between Spark dataframe and Cassandra table. For instance, the `value` is now a double floating-point type in both Spark and Cassandra. Is `double` in Spark equivalent to `double` in Cassandra?

Comment: yes, SCC takes care for type conversions - it there were incompatible it would throw an exception...